Spherical Harmonic Expansion of Green's function?
I am not using a textbook, nor am I a physics major, I am doing this without any official resources, so bear that in mind if anything looks out of the ordinary.
Green's function for Poisson's Equation with a Dirichlet boundary condition on a sphere of radius $a$ is
$$\tag{1}G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}') = \left(\frac{1}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|}-\frac{\dfrac{a}{r'}}{\left|\textbf{x}-\dfrac{a^2}{r'^2}\textbf{x}'\right|}\right).$$
I wanted to use this to solve the following Poisson's Equation:
$$\tag{2}\nabla^2 V = \rho\frac{4\pi}{\epsilon_0}=\cases{1 & $0\le a \le r$ \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}} \\ V(a,\theta,\phi) = V(\theta,\phi) = a\cos\theta \sin\phi.$$
The solution using Green's function would then be
$$V(r,\theta,\phi) = \tag{3}\int_0^a r'^2 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi 1\cdot G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}')\sin\theta' \mathrm{d}\theta' \mathrm{d}\phi' \mathrm{d}r' - a^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi V(\theta,\phi)\frac{\partial G}{\partial r'}\sin\theta' \mathrm{d}\theta' \mathrm{d}\phi'.$$
Someone recommended to me that I expand $G$ in terms of spherical harmonics, and according to this resource, a spherical harmonic expansion of Green's function for the point charge inside the sphere $\frac{1}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|}$ would then be:
$$\tag{4}\label{eq:4}\frac{1}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^l_<}{r^{l+1}_>}P_l\cos\gamma.$$
There are some things that don't make sense leading up to deriving this. From this source, we start with the case of $\dfrac{1}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|}\Biggr|_{\textbf{x}' = R \\ \theta = 0}$ and performing a Taylor series on the piecewise definitions, I get:
$$\tag{5} 
\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{\left|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'\right|}\Biggr|_{\textbf{x}' = R \\ \theta = 0} &= \cases{\dfrac{1}{r-R} & $r-R\ge 0$ 
\\ 
\frac{1}{R-r} & $r-R < 0$}\\ 
&= 
\cases{-\frac{1}{R}\left(1+\dfrac{r}{R}+\Big(\frac{r}{R}\Big)^2+ ... \right) = -\frac{1}{R}\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty \Big(\frac{r}{R}\Big)^l & $r\ge R$ 
\\ 
\frac{1}{R}\bigg(1+\frac{r}{R}+\Big(\frac{r}{R}\Big)^2+ ... \bigg) = \frac{1}{R}\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty \Big(\frac{r}{R}\Big)^l & $r<R$}
\end{align}$$
where I have centered both at $r = 0$. Both of these pieces are defined incorrectly, and I don't see what the issue is. Also, if I tried to define the Taylor series for $r=\infty$ like I felt it wanted me to for $r > R$, I would not have a convergent Taylor series.
Beyond just that issue, I don't know what our combination of these definitions into a single sum which yields $\eqref{eq:4}$ is supposed to mean, and part of the problem is that I do not know how $r_<$ or $r_>$ are defined. What are they physically, and what are their standard forms from which they were translated from and then substituted for?

I do not know how $r_<$ or $r_>$ are defined. Your first linked resource defines them.

@Ghoster "where r>,r< are the greater and lesser of r, r′", okay... so now the problem is I don't understand what that means or how it is defined as an expression i.e. what is being substituted for it. Like for example, would $$r_>$$ be defined as $$\Big(\frac{R}{r}\Big)$$? But honestly, that's more for later, could we try to keep this to the Taylor series expansions for now?

No, $r_>$ isn’t a dimensionless ratio! It’s either $r$ or $r’$… whichever is larger.

For $r>R$ you should be expanding in powers of $R/r$, since this is less than 1,

The left side of (5) is missing the vertical bars.

$\textbf{x}' = R$ is also missing vertical bars.

@Ghoster So for the case $r>R$, then $r_> = r$, and for $r < R$, then $r_> = r'$, right? Did the R get replaced with either $r_>$ or $r_<$? I'm not sure how exactly these two cases were combined to get (4) so the substitutions are not immediately obvious

@Ghoster Also, your comment on my Taylor series expansion (and I recalled seeing this when I verified my result with wolframalpha), the result for $r>R$ yielded a Laurent series, not a Taylor series. I've only ever done 2 Laurent series before and I've never taken a class in complex analysis, so I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. For context, the Laurent series was taken for $r=\infty$ and it yielded the correct result. So, we need to do a Laurent series then, got it

It’s a Taylor series in $R/r$; $r$ and $R$ are interchangeable so there’s nothing that makes $r$ more important. But you can certainly consider it a Laurent series in $r$ if that makes you happy.

So for the case $r>R$, then $r_>=r$, and for $r<R$, then $r_>=r′$, right? Yes, but since you insist on calling $r’$ $R$, $r_>$ is $R$ when $r<R$.

The first simplification is to make things dimensionless:
$$
\Delta V+\rho=0\\
V(r=1)=U(\theta,\phi)
$$
Next, break up the problem in terms of homogeneities:
$$
V=V_P+V_L\\
\Delta V_L=0\\
V_L(r=1)=U\\
\Delta V_P+\rho=0\\
V_P(r=1)=0
$$
For $V_p$ you can use your Green’s function:
$$
V_P=G_P*\rho
$$
Similarly, for $V_l$ you can use the Green’s function:
$$
V_L=G_L*U
$$
The point of separating the inhomogeneities is to add the various Green’s functions.
In your case though, a spherical harmonic expansion is more appropriate. Expand:
$$
V=\sum V_l^m(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)\\
\rho=\sum \rho_l^m(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)\\
U=\sum U_l^mY_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
You now have to solve independent, second order ODE’s:
$$
\frac{(r^2(V_l^m)’)’}{r^2}-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}V_l^m+\rho_l^m(r)=0 \\
V_l^m(1)=U_l^m \tag{*}
$$
where you use the fact that:
$$
\Delta[f(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)]=\frac{(r^2f’)’}{r^2}Y_l^m-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}fY_l^m
$$
Which is precisely what motivates the spherical harmonics as a way to solve the problem by separation of variables.
You may think that the problem is underdetermined but regularity at zero when your domain is the ball gives the second boundary condition. In practice, if the charge density is not "too accumulated" at $0$ (for example a finite limit of $\rho_l^m$), there will be a unique bounded solution  up to  at zero (up to a multiplicative factor). This will be the relevant solution. A similar analysis holds when the domain is the complement of the ball. In fact, it will be the other solution will typically be independent solution to the ball solution.
Your homework problem was clearly designed for this method as the problem just need three terms:
$$
\rho = \rho_0^0Y_0^0 \quad U=U_1^1Y_1^1+U_1^{-1}Y_1^{-1}
$$
However, in your case $U_1^1 = -(U_1^{-1})^*$. You can take the imaginary part of the solution with $U_1^{-1}=0$, so you only have two terms to consider.
You can solve the $l=m=0$ equation with Gauss’ law:
$$
V_0^0= \rho_0^0\frac{1-r^2}6
$$
You can solve the $l=m=1$ equation with a power law ansatz:
$$
V_1^1= U_1^1r
$$
To come full circle, you can even expand the Green’s functions in spherical coordinates. I will use the convention that spherical harmonics are orthonormal:
$$
\int Y_l^mY_{l'}^{m'}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi = \delta_{ll'}\delta_{mm'}
$$
For the Poisson problem, you already have it:
$$
G_P=\sum \left(\frac{H(r-r')}{2l+1}\left(r'(r'/r)^{l+1}-r'^2(rr')^l\right)+\frac{H(r'-r)}{2l+1}\left(r'(r/r')^l-r'^2(rr')^l\right)\right)Y_l^m(\theta’,\phi’)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
with $H$ the Heaviside function. For the Laplace problem you just need to decompose:
$$
\frac{\delta(\theta-\theta’)\delta(\phi-\phi’)}{\sin\theta’}=\sum Y_l^m(\theta’,\phi’)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)\\
G_L=\sum r^lY_l^m(\theta’,\phi’)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
This comes from the fact that the general solution of $(*)$ (with the correct boundary condition at $0$) is:
$$
V_l^m(r) = U_l^mr^l+\int_0^r\frac{\rho_l^m(s)}{2l+1}\left(s(s/r)^{l+1}-s^2(rs)^l\right)ds+\int_r^1\frac{\rho_l^m(s)}{2l+1}\left(s(r/s)^l-s^2(rs)^l\right)ds
$$

Okay I follow the general idea. You created a spherical harmonic representation for the solution, the forcing term, and the boundary condition, and then plugged these into Poisson's equation to create: $$\Delta V_l^m(r) + \rho_l^m(r) = 0 \rightarrow \Bigg(\frac{(r^2 (V_l^m(r))')'}{r^2}\Bigg) +  \rho_l^m(r) = 0$$? I can't quite figure out how you got that ODE, specifically where the $l(l+1)V_l^m(r)$ term came from

I just saw the edit made, thank you for tentatively updating this to help me! I was unaware of that identity; I am self-taught so I am picking up all of this as I go, I'm not in a course or anything like that. So, after representing our functions as spherical harmonic expansions, our Poisson's equation becomes: $$\sum\sum\Bigg[\Delta V_l^m(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) + \rho_l^m(r) Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)\Bigg] = 0$$, and with that identity (which I intend to learn how to prove later) $$\sum\sum \Bigg[\frac{(r^2 V_l^m(r)')'}{r^2}-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}V_l^m(r)+\rho_l^m(r)\Bigg]Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)=0$$

I don't know what "regularity" means. From the context clues of applying a boundary condition based on whether we're inside or outside of the sphere, I immediately think you're talking about modifying the radial normal mode ($V_l^m(r)$ in this case) so the solution is bounded at the origin if our solution is inside the sphere, and at $r\rightarrow \infty$ outside the sphere. Is that right? Would we define our solution as $$V_l^m(r) = ar^l + br{-(l+1)}$$?

After I've figured out the boundary conditions, so I'm not messaging you back and forth for the next week, the comprehensive list of things I don't understand are 1)why we "just need" the solutions to the ODE for $l=m=0$ and $l=m=1$? What do we do with these solutions, and why did we find them at these specific values of $l$ and $m$?, 2) the boundary condition representation in spherical harmonics gave me $l = 1, m = 0,\pm 1$, will $G_L$ expanded in spherical coordinates take on those values of $l$ and $m$ as well? 3) What did "close the circle" mean?


when you say I "already have it", are you talking about Green's function in equation (4)? Or equation (1) which when expanded in spherical coordinates is: $$G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}') = 4\pi \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2l+1}\Bigg(\frac{r'^l}{r^{l+1}}-\frac{a}{r'}\frac{r^l}{(a^2/r')^{l+1}}\Bigg)\sum_{m=-l}^l Y_l^{m*}(\theta',\phi')Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$$?


One last clarifying question, but are those $H()$'s in your Green's function, Heaviside step functions? After that's answered, I think I'll go ahead and leave this answer here to come back to later. This is certainly a higher level problem than what my post-undergrad in meteorology self is currently capable of, and while I did take a couple months to learn about spherical harmonics on my own outside of college, and did a couple Laplace's equation problems, I think I still have a ways to go after seeing this. Zangwill's E.dynamics, right? Or were you paraphrasing from a different body of text?

You can see similar discussions in any EM textbook, like Griffiths' and Jackson's (never used Zangwill, but it is pretty standard as well)

If you have a more meteorological background, you have similar equations in your field as well. For example for quasi-geostrophic equations, getting the geopotential from the vorticity is the same as solving a (2D) Poisson problem. On a spherical surface as the Earth, this can be done using spherical harmonics.

While waiting for my books to arrive, I worked out $V_0^0(r)$ using Gauss's Law. Given that our electric charge density could also be written as $$\rho_0^0 \Theta(R-r)$$, when we use Divergence theorem to find (the magnitude of) our Electric field $E(r)_0^0$, we get an Electric field with 2 pieces, one inside the sphere and the other outside, and integrating to find $V(r)0^0$ also gives 2 pieces. Do you agree there is a piece for $r>R$, but we neglect it as our only focus is inside the sphere? My inside piece is correct, and my outside piece, I got $V_0^0(r)=\rho_0^0 \frac{R^3}{3r}|{r\ge R}$

Yes, I only looked at inside the ball. This is because if $\rho$ is supported inside and will not influence the outside. Your result for outside the ball is correct, if you set $\epsilon_0=1$. It is just Coulomb's law for the total integrated charge in the ball, which follows from Newton's theorem.

I’m finally back up to speed on spherical harmonics and I managed to work out how $\Delta[f(\theta,\phi)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)]$ using a clever substitution. Before I moved on to green’s function, I wanted to clarify something with how you converted the boundary condition to a spherical harmonic. $$U = a\cos\theta\sin\phi$$ this doesn’t exactly have a spherical harmonic representation and we end up having to brute force the orthogonality integral. However, I think I could get l=m=1 if I offset $\theta$ $$\alpha = \theta-\pi/2$$ $Y_l^m(\alpha,\phi)$ and $l=m=1$. Is that how you got $l=m=1$?

I forgot to get back to you on this, but I did eventually fully solve this problem using the spherical harmonic expansion representation of the functions to build 2 separate ODEs. I ended up forgetting to come back to this and working through the integrals. I will try to work through them eventually.
